# How To Serve Uploaded Images From OpenShift DATA_DIR

Tags: java, openshift

My app runs on JBoss EAP and I want to upload images to the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR and then save their relative paths in the MySQL DB because I need to construct a path to the images and later serve them to the browser when needed.

If my `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` path is `/var/lib/openshift/5364c54ce0b8cd80180001f7/app-root/data/` and I want `schoolpics/federaluniversity/uniben-1/` inside it to save a file `logo.png` such that the full path will be

`/var/lib/openshift/5364c54ce0b8cd80180001f7/app-root/data/schoolpics/federaluniversity/uniben-1/logo.png`

How to achieve this in term of storing in database, and opening using URL of image in a web page, since the `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` seems to be outside the `webroot` of the app.

Comment: All questions have same priority here. "Urgent" is irrelevant info.

Comment: Set a link in a public dir to the data dir.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this issue was to create a servlet that would serve the images from the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, the servlet also supplies a way to write the images to the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR also, you can check out this forum post for more information: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift

Comment: Thanks. First I have a failed attempt to move a file (uploaded to tmp) to schoolpics/federaluniversity/uniben-1/ within OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. The code log is here http://ur1.ca/hi8pd

Comment: Did you create that directory before you tried to move the image to it?

Comment: I have confirmed that the directory paths are created. It seems moving the uploaded file is what fails.

Comment: The images are now saved to a folder called logos within the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, but I need to display them in an Ajax client. I tried www.theappurl.com/logos/logo1.png and got a 404 response page. Is there a way to construct a path to the uploaded images, since OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR is outside the webroot?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. I have exposed my data dir using a handler in Undertow, but when I try to access my files, I get a 404. The server log points out `WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies`.