# Uploading images to a specific place in a Java web server

Tags: java, image, jsp, webserver, openshift

I'm working on a Java web application. As part of this web app, I have a database containing objects with image file paths associated with them. By simply dragging and dropping, I was able to put these images in an `images` folder in my web server. Their path in Eclipse appears to be `src/main/webapp/images`.

When I want to access these images in a JSP page, I simply make an `img` tag with `src="/images/fileName.png"` and it works perfectly fine.

Here's the issue. I want users to be able to upload their own images to the web server, storing the filenames in the database. I've been looking around for a way to do this, but I'm having trouble finding a detailed answer. What can I use to write the images to that specific folder, `images`, in my web server? Thanks in advance.

For reference, here is an example of a fileName: `/images/propane.png`

And here is an example of me calling it in JSP: `<img src="/images/propane.png">`

I realize this may be a kind of basic question, but I'm really having trouble with getting the image to be stored in that specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that anything uploaded to src/main/webapp/images will be deleted when you deploy a new version of your application to OpenShift. You can save and serve the images from the `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`, which is the only directory you can write to that won't be deleted when you redeploy your application. You also need to be aware that the files in `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` are not shared across gears in a scaled OpenShift application. So if your application is scaled, you need to store user uploaded images somewhere like Dropbox or Amazon S3.

For details on how to serve images from `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` via your Java application, look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163138/how-to-serve-uploaded-images-from-openshift-data-dir) and [this OpenShift tutorial](https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into those two links you provided and test them out.

Comment: I tried the OpenShift tutorial and I got the following error:

Comment: `/var/lib/openshift/l3tt3rsAndNumb3rs/app-root/data/quartermaster (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed, or what might be causing this?

Comment: @jpabene Did you SSH into the server and verify that the directory exists? It looks like you are trying to use a subdirectory named 'quartermaster', did you create that directory? `/var/lib/openshift/l3tt3rsAndNumb3rs/app-root/data/` would be the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR path if your app's name is 'l3tt3rsAndNumb3rs`. The quartermaster directory would not be there unless you create it.